# In python, use Gradient Descent to print out values of theta0 and theta1

Tags: python

This is the condition:
  we use the Gradient descent methods to find a "better" values for theta0 and theta1 that minimizes the error. Gradient descent is an iterative algorithm. It computes values of theta0 and theta1 in the direction of reaching the minimum point in the error function. The iterative formulas using L2 loss function for theta0 and theta1 are given by:

```
0=0−∗(∑(1∗+0)−)

1=1−∗(∑(1∗+0−)∗
```

The alpha is called the "learning rate". It is important to pick a good value for alpha so that convergence is not too slow (small alpha) or be at the risk of over shooting the minimum point (large alpha). You may have to experiemnt with few alphas to find something that works.

print out the theta0 and theta1 values for each iteration in your function.

```
# given the observed data (obsX,obsY), learning rate (alpha), and desired error threshold, 
# the function returns theta0 and theta1 when it reaches the error threshold.
# The convergence is reached when the abs(newError - oldError) is less than the threshold.

# BEGIN SOLUTION  
def gd2(obsX, obsY, alpha, threshold):
    """
    Input : observed vectors X, Y, alpha and threshold
    Return theta0, theta1 from Gradient Descent L2 loss algorithm
    Return: Iterations and L2 Error
    """


# END SOLUTION

[theta0,theta1,newError,iterations] = gd2(x,y,0.01,0.000001)
print(iterations)
```

and I wrote this code:

```
      def gd2(obsX, obsY, alpha, threshold):
        """
        Input : observed vectors X, Y, alpha and threshold
        Return theta0, theta1 from Gradient Descent L2 loss algorithm
        Return: Iterations and L2 Error
        """
          theta0 = 0
          theta1 = 1
          new_error = sqerror(theta0, theta1)
          old_error = sqerror(theta0, theta1)
          number_of_iterations = 0

          theta0_theta1_l2_error_group = []

          while 1:
             old_theta0 = theta0
             old_theta1 = theta1

             theta0 = theta0 - alpha * sum([(old_theta0 + old_theta1 * obsX[i] - obsY[i]) for i in range(len(df_cleaned))])
             theta1 = theta1 - alpha * sum([(old_theta0 + old_theta1 * obsX[i] - obsY[i]) * obsX[i] for i in range(len(df_cleaned))])

             new_error = old_error
             old_error = sqerror(theta0, theta1)

             theta0_theta1_l2_error_group.append([theta0, theta1, old_error])

             print(theta0, theta1, old_error)
             number_of_iterations = number_of_iterations + 1

             if math.fabs(new_error - old_error) < threshold:
                   break

         print(number_of_iterations)
         return [theta0, theta1, new_error, iter(theta0_theta1_l2_error_group)]


# END SOLUTION

[theta0,theta1,newError,iterations] = gd2(x,y,0.01,0.000001)
print(iterations)
```

but i got this error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-61-1bfd075bd630> in <module>
     42 # END SOLUTION
     43 
---> 44 [theta0,theta1,newError,iterations] = gd2(x,y,0.01,0.000001)
     45 print(iterations)

<ipython-input-61-1bfd075bd630> in gd2(obsX, obsY, alpha, threshold)
     12     theta0 = 0
     13     theta1 = 1
---> 14     new_error = sqerror(theta0, theta1)
     15     old_error = sqerror(theta0, theta1)
     16     number_of_iterations = 0

TypeError: sqerror() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'theta0' and 'theta1'
```

what does that mean? how to fix that??

Comment: Please look at this type: `tptal2 = total2 - alpha *(sum(total2 * obsX + total1 - obsY)*obsX)`

Comment: The x and y 's value have already given in the previous part, that's why i just use obsX = x, obsY = y

Comment: oh, i was changed tptal2 to total2, but i still got 1000....